# Windows 8 offline updates

Tags: update, windows-8

I am trying to update a Windows 8 installation on a machine that is not connected to the internet.

I have been told that standalone installers exist but ultimately the Microsoft sites just direct me to run windows update which isn't an option. Where can I find the standalone installers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [WSUS Offline Update](http://www.wsusoffline.net/) to update computers that aren't connected to the internet.  But you'll need a computer that does have access to Windows Update to create the offline install media first.

[image: WSUS Offline Generator]

Then you run the installer on the target computer with the update media targeted:

[image]